# How to end a state in Phaser as well as navigate back to a previous state

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am new to Phaser and I have been writing a multilevel puzzle game.

Hierarchically the states go something like this - Menu -> Level 1 -> Level 2 -> etc.

Now suppose I am playing Level 1 and either after level completion or in the middle when I press back key I want to be able to go back to menu state and from there I want to be able to navigate back to the forward levels if I want to keep playing.

Initially I assumed `this.state.start( 'anyLevel')` could take me to any state and the state would run normally as when run for the first time since boot. But navigating back to states that have already been fired once is proving difficult. What I need is to be able to go back to a previous state and the state should behave as it would when run first time since booting.
I read somewhere that I need to clean up the state via `shutDown()` before starting a new state and I did:

```
  shutdown: function() {
    this.game.world.removeAll();
   }
```

before starting every new level but it still did not help. I also tried using:

```
this.state.start( 'anyLevel', true, false);
```

but proved useless. Debugger does not show errors which means syntactically the program is correct but I am not grasping the mechanism properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when making a level based game I would not recommend putting each level in a separate state, see answers about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41379578/1745616) and [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/5446-how-to-create-multiple-levels/#comment-109375).

Other than that, I have always just used `state.start()` like you posted and it works fine, so something like this:

```
// from level select state, switch to game state..
this.game.state.start('MyGameState');

// ..and from game state, switch back to level select state
this.game.state.start('MySelectState');
```

So what errors or unexpected behaviour do you get? Maybe your problems occur because the object variables you are using in the state are not "connected" to that state? I mean, the sprite and enemy etc. variables are they created outside the state, or are they part of the state like in the code below?

```
GameState = function(game) {
    // reference to main game object
    this.game = game;

    // object variables are part of this state
    this.myplayer;
    this.myenemies;
    //..etc.
};

GameState.prototype = {

    create: function() {
        this.myplayer = this.game.add.sprite(100, 100, 'mysprites', 'smileydude');
        this.myenemies = this.game.add.group();
        //..etc.
    },
    update: function() {
    },
    //..
    doResetCurrentLevel: function() {
        this.state.start('MyGameState', true, false);
    }
};
```

Btw notice how you can simply reset the current state by just starting it. Starting a state will trigger the `create()` function again to clean up and refresh the sprites and enemies variables. I'm not entirely sure how this works, but I've always assumed the JavaScript garbage collector takes care of this.

Comment: Thanks for the advise on multi-level games. But what is the proper way to end an old state in Phaser while entering a new state ? Do I have to manually destroy each and everything in shutDown()  ?

Comment: Interphase 1 has a State Manager Guide which covers the `shutdown` state.There he states that Phaser will take care of most of its own cleanup. Further, "if your game relies on an external API then you may wish to close any open connections. If there are any custom Game Objects you’ve created that have more complex set-ups then you should destroy them here as well, to stop them from bleeding over into the next state." (pg. 64) So for the most part you should be fine just letting it be.